# How can I add a css property to the first div with a specific class name?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to add a bottom margin to the first `<div>` with a class "unit".

```
<div id="wrapper-related-albums">
   <div class="header">...</div>
   <div class="unit">...</div> //add margin-bottom to this one!!!!
   <div class="header">...</div>
   <div class="unit">...</div>
</div>



#wrapper-related-albums .unit:first-child {margin-bottom:20px;} // doesn't work!!!
#wrapper-related-albums .unit:first-of-type {margin-bottom:20px;} // doesn't work!!!
```

Comment: It has an id. why don't you use it?

Comment: `:first-of-type` only works on element selectors, not classes.  Why do you need a bottom margin added to this element?

Comment: [`:first-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo) looks for an element that is the first sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent element and [`:first-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#structural-pseudos) represents an element that is the first child of some other element - attributes are ignored.

Comment: with #wrapper-related-albums div.unit, they both get a margin... i only want the first .unit of div.wrapper-related-albums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few options, depending on your markup:

Second child with class unit:

```css
#wrapper-related-albums .unit:nth-of-type(2) { }
#wrapper-related-albums .unit:nth-child(2) { }
```

Adjacent sibling (with class unit) of the first element:

```css
#wrapper-related-albums :first-child + .unit {  }
```

I don't believe there's any way to simply select "the first `.unit`", but you can add the margin to all *except* the last one, if it always falls last:

```css
#wrapper-related-albums .unit { margin-bottom: 20px; }

/* negate the above rule */
#wrapper-related-albums .unit:last-child { margin-bottom: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 4):

### More General/Flexible Solution

Wesley's answer serves well for your particular html markup, as it assumes the `.unit` is going to be the second element in the listing. So in your case, that may be so, and his solution works well. However, if someone were seeking a more general solution the following is what should be done:

```css
#wrapper-related-albums .unit { 
    /* code for the first one */ 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#wrapper-related-albums .unit ~ .unit { 
    /* code for all the following ones */ 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Using the general sibling selector (`~`) like this will override all but the first `.unit`, allowing the first `.unit` to be anywhere in the wrapper (not just in position #2, and the position need not be known in advance). [Here's a fiddle that illustrates it using a `color` change.](http://jsfiddle.net/qSK7J/)